# Not able to rotate the grid in usercontrol from the centre of grid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have one main page and one user control and have one button in User control with events for rotating.Events are firing for rotating but not from the centre but from corner.But I want rotate the grid withing the centre.So the user can easily rotate the see from different angle.I was trying to build one application for building map.so the user can rotate the floor to see from different angle ..Please help how to fix this issue
My User Control Xamal :

```
    <UserControl x:Class="Floorsreen.FloorUserControl"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="600" Background="Yellow"   >



        <Grid Width="600" Height="600" Background="Yellow" >

            <Grid Width="500" Height="500" Background="Wheat" Name="my_grid">
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="transform" />
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                     <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                     <RowDefinition Height="20"  />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="20"  />

                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>



            </Grid>


        </Grid>
            <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="516,582,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>

My UserControl code behind:

    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;


namespace Floorsreen
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for FloorUserControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class FloorUserControl : UserControl

    {

        public FloorUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
            DoubleAnimation rotateAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                From = 0,
                To = 90,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0))
            };
            Storyboard.SetTarget(rotateAnimation, my_grid);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(rotateAnimation, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"));

            storyboard.Children.Add(rotateAnimation);
            storyboard.Begin();

        }

    }

}
```

And my Main page xamal:

```
<Window x:Class="Floorsreen.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Floorsreen" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="1000">

    <Window.Resources>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>


        <view:FloorUserControl />


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: You haven't specified anything that `rotateAnimation` should do, e.g. set its `To` or `By` or `Duration` property. Read this first: [Animation Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/animation-overview).

Comment: Thank you...I have updated the rotateAnimation code in user conrol code behind..now the problem is grid is not rotating from the centre of grid panel..instead it is rotating from the corner..Is there any solution for that to rotate from the centre..

Comment: Besides the RenderTransform property, there is also a RenderTransformOrigin. Please try to read a minimum amount of documentation before starting to code. Also try to reduce the amount of code you are showing in a StackOverflow question to a relevant minimum. Do we really need to know that there are hundreds of StackPanels in your XAML?

Comment: Thank you now it is working...Only problem when click the button again it starts to rotate from the begninning instead of from 90 degree, how to fix this so the user can rotate from end of postition

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the `RenderTransformOrigin`.  This property takes two doubles, usually from 0 - 1, which specify X and Y pivot location in percent.  Meaning `RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"` will start in the center where the default `RenderTransformOrigin="0, 0"` is the upper left corner.  `RenderTransformOrigin="1, 1"` is bottom right and so on.

To rotate in the center you need to add this attachable property to your grid. 
Example:

```
<Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted... It's the answer the OP needs based on the question and the written XAML.  *shrugs*